# Receive callback when Paypal Minibrowser is closed

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

Using the Express Checkout flow for Digital Goods, the user is forwarded into a Minibrowser window to login with their credentials and confirm the payment. When the user clicks Cancel in the Minibrowser or confirms the payment, they are redirected to the cancel or return URLs provided during the Paypal Checkout and from there I can redirect them in the parent window to the fulfillment page as described here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ClosingWindow/

However if the user just closes the Minibrowser window itself, the Cancel URL is never opened and the redirect in the parent window does not happen. How can I handle the case that a user closes the Minibrowser so I can send them to the cancel page?

**Update**
The cancel URL is called on window close inside the parent window, if I set expType to 'light' in Javascript. However, it is not called if I set expType to 'instant', which is the desired one. Is this a bug?

Comment: Is there a way you can redirect them to the cancel page automatically before they click Cancel or Confirm? Then if they click confirm it will just carry on as usual. Cancel should act just like if they had closed the window.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am calling from a Flash application, so I need some kind of callback to wake Flash when the payment process has ended. I found that the cancel URL is actually called inside the parent window when the user closes the Minibrowser, but only if I set the expType to light. With instant (desired) it does not work. I will add this to the question.